# Peak and Flag Codility latest chellange

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to solve the latest codility.com question (just for enhance my skills). I tried allot but not getting more than 30 marks there so now curious what exactly I am missing in my solution.

**The question says**

A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. A peak is an array element which is larger than its neighbours. More precisely, it is an index P such that

```
0 < P < N − 1 and A[P − 1] < A[P] > A[P + 1]
```

For example, the following array A:

```
A[0] = 1 
A[1] = 5 
A[2] = 3 
A[3] = 4 
A[4] = 3 
A[5] = 4 
A[6] = 1 
A[7] = 2 
A[8] = 3 
A[9] = 4 
A[10] = 6 
A[11] = 2
```

has exactly four peaks: elements 1, 3, 5 and 10.

You are going on a trip to a range of mountains whose relative heights are represented by array A. You have to choose how many flags you should take with you. The goal is to set the maximum number of flags on the peaks, according to certain rules.

Flags can only be set on peaks. What's more, if you take K flags, then the distance between any two flags should be greater than or equal to K. The distance between indices P and Q is the absolute value |P − Q|.

For example, given the mountain range represented by array A, above, with N = 12, if you take:

```
> two flags, you can set them on peaks 1 and 5; 

> three flags, you can set them on peaks 1, 5 and 10; 

> four flags, you can set only three flags, on peaks 1, 5 and 10.
```

You can therefore set a maximum of three flags in this case.

Write a function that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns the maximum number of flags that can be set on the peaks of the array.
For example, given the array above

the function should return 3, as explained above.

Assume that:

N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];

each element of array A is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000,000].

Complexity:

expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the
storage required for input arguments).

So I tried this code according to my understanding of question

```
var A = [1,5,3,4,3,4,1,2,3,4,6,2];

function solution(A) {
 array = new Array();  
   for (i = 1; i < A.length - 1; i++) {  
    if (A[i - 1] < A[i] && A[i + 1] < A[i]) {  
     array.push(i);  
    }  
   }  

  //console.log(A);
  //console.log(array);
  var position = array[0];
  var counter = 1;
  var len = array.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(array[i+1] - position) >= len) {
        position = array[i+1];
        counter ++;
        }
    }

  console.log("total:",counter);
  return counter;

}
```

The above code works for sample array elements: `[1,5,3,4,3,4,1,2,3,4,6,2]` 
Get peaks at indices: `[1, 3, 5, 10]` and set flags at `1, 5, and 10 (total 3)`

But codility.com says it fails on array `[7, 10, 4, 5, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 3, 3, 7]` 
My code get peaks at indices: `[1, 4, 6, 8]` and set flags at 1 and 6 (total 2)
but coditity.com says it should be 3 flags. (no idea why)
Am I miss-understanding the question ?

Please I am only looking for the hint/algo. I know this question is already asked by someone and solved on private chatroom but on that page I tried to get the help with that person but members rather flagging my posts as inappropriate answer so I am asking the question here again.

P.S: You can try coding the challenge yourself [here](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/10-prime_and_composite_numbers/flags/)!

Comment: It should be 3 flags at positions 1, 4 and 8. |1 - 4| = 3 >= 3 (number of flags) and |4 - 8| = 4 >= 3 (number of flags). P and Q are indices

Comment: How are you calculating K ? 
What I understand that it is number of peaks we got which is 4 for the array [7, 10, 4, 5, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 3, 3, 7] so we will check difference of 4

Comment: And obviously I am placing the 1st flag on 1st index.. and then moving forward to check difference for the next flag.

Comment: You're trying to set 4 flags and ultimately end up setting 2 flags. If you find you can't set 4 flags then you need to restart to try and set 3 flags, or you'll compare with the wrong distance (4 instead of 3).

Comment: I don't understand why can't we put flags at positions 1 and 3 when we are taking two flags!?? |3-1| = 2 >= num_of_flags. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing 100% PHP solution :)

```
function solution($A)
{
    $p = array(); // peaks
    for ($i=1; $i<count($A)-1; $i++)
        if ($A[$i] > $A[$i-1] && $A[$i] > $A[$i+1])
            $p[] = $i;

    $n = count($p);
    if ($n <= 2)
        return $n;

    $maxFlags = min(intval(ceil(sqrt(count($A)))), $n); // max number of flags
    $distance = $maxFlags; // required distance between flags
    // try to set max number of flags, then 1 less, etc... (2 flags are already set)
    for ($k = $maxFlags-2; $k > 0; $k--)
    {
        $left = $p[0];
        $right = $p[$n-1];
        $need = $k; // how many more flags we need to set

        for ($i = 1; $i<=$n-2; $i++)
        {
            // found one more flag for $distance
            if ($p[$i]-$left >= $distance && $right-$p[$i] >= $distance)
            {
                if ($need == 1)
                    return $k+2;
                $need--;
                $left = $p[$i];
            }

            if ($right - $p[$i] <= $need * ($distance+1))
                break; // impossible to set $need more flags for $distance
        }

        if ($need == 0)
            return $k+2;

        $distance--;
    }
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: failures on Codility's server:example
example test✘WRONG ANSWER
got 2 expected 3
expand allCorrectness tests
▶extreme_min
extreme min test✔OK
▶extreme_without_peaks
test without peaks✔OK
▶prime_length
test with prime sequence length✘WRONG ANSWER
got 3 expected 1
▶anti_bin_search
anti bin_search test✘WRONG ANSWER
got 4 expected 7
▶simple1
simple test✘WRONG ANSWER
got 2 expected 4
▶simple2
second simple test✔OK
expand allPerformance tests
▶medium_random
chaotic medium sequences, length = ~5,000✘WRONG ANSWER
got 70 expected 625

Answer (score 6):

This is a solution with better upper complexity bounds:

- time complexity: `O(sqrt(N) * log(N))`
- space complexity: `O(1)` (over the original input storage)

### Python implementation

```js
from math import sqrt

def transform(A):
    peak_pos = len(A)
    last_height = A[-1]
    for p in range(len(A) - 1, 0, -1):
        if (A[p - 1] < A[p] > last_height):
            peak_pos = p
        last_height = A[p]
        A[p] = peak_pos
    A[0] = peak_pos

def can_fit_flags(A, k):
    flag = 1 - k
    for i in range(k):
        # plant the next flag at A[flag + k]
        if flag + k > len(A) - 1:
            return False
        flag = A[flag + k]
    return flag < len(A)  # last flag planted successfully

def solution(A):
    transform(A)
    lower = 0
    upper = int(sqrt(len(A))) + 2
    assert not can_fit_flags(A, k=upper)
    while lower < upper - 1:
        next = (lower + upper) // 2
        if can_fit_flags(A, k=next):
            lower = next
        else:
            upper = next
    return lower
```

### Description

`O(N)` preprocessing (done inplace):

```
A[i] := next peak or end position after or at position i
        (i for a peak itself, len(A) after last peak)
```

If we can plant `k` flags then we can certainly plant `k' < k` flags as well.
If we can not plant `k` flags then we certainly can not plant `k' > k` flags either.
We can always set 0 flags.
Let us assume we can not set `X` flags.
Now we can use binary search to find out exactly how many flags can be planted.

```
Steps:
  1. X/2
  2. X/2 +- X/4
  3. X/2 +- X/4 +- X/8
  ...
  log2(X) steps in total
```

With the preprocessing done before, each step testing whether `k` flags can be planted can be performed in `O(k)` operations:

- flag(0) = next(0)
- flag(1) = next(flag(1) + k)
  ...
- flag(k-1) = next(flag(k-2) + k)

total cost - worst case - when `X - 1` flags can be planted:

> == X * (1/2 + 3/4 + ... + (2^k - 1)/(2^k))
>    == X * (log2(X) - 1 + (<1))
>    <= X * log(X)

Using `X == N` would work, and would most likely also be sublinear, but is not good enough to use in a proof that the total upper bound for this algorithm is under `O(N)`.

Now everything depends on finding a good `X`, and it since `k` flags take about `k^2` positions to fit, it seems like a good upper limit on the number of flags should be found somewhere around `sqrt(N)`.

If `X == sqrt(N)` or something close to it works, then we get an upper bound of `O(sqrt(N) * log(sqrt(N)))` which is definitely sublinear and since `log(sqrt(N)) == 1/2 * log(N)` that upper bound is equivalent to `O(sqrt(N) * log(N))`.

Let's look for a more exact upper bound on the number of required flags around `sqrt(N)`:

- we know `k` flags requires `Nk := k^2 - k + 3` flags
- by solving the equation `k^2 - k + 3 - N = 0` over `k` we find that if `k >= 3`, then any number of flags <= the resulting `k` can fit in some sequence of length N and a larger one can not; solution to that equation is `1/2 * (1 + sqrt(4N - 11))`
- for `N >= 9` we know we can fit 3 flags
  ==> for `N >= 9`, `k = floor(1/2 * (1 + sqrt(4N - 11))) + 1` is a strict upper bound on the number of flags we can fit in `N`
- for `N < 9` we know 3 is a strict upper bound but those cases do not concern us for finding the big-O algorithm complexity

> floor(1/2 * (1 + sqrt(4N - 11))) + 1
>     == floor(1/2 + sqrt(N - 11/4)) + 1
>     <= floor(sqrt(N - 11/4)) + 2
>     <= floor(sqrt(N)) + 2

==> `floor(sqrt(N)) + 2` is also a good strict upper bound for a number of flags that can fit in `N` elements + this one holds even for `N < 9` so it can be used as a generic strict upper bound in our implementation as well

If we choose `X = floor(sqrt(N)) + 2` we get the following total algorithm upper bound:

```
O((floor(sqrt(N)) + 2) * log(floor(sqrt(N)) + 2))
   {floor(...) <= ...}
O((sqrt(N) + 2) * log(sqrt(N) + 2))
   {for large enough N >= 4: sqrt(N) + 2 <= 2 * sqrt(N)}
O(2 * sqrt(N) * log(2 * sqrt(N)))
   {lose the leading constant}
O(sqrt(N) * (log(2) + loq(sqrt(N)))
O(sqrt(N) * log(2) + sqrt(N) * log(sqrt(N)))
   {lose the lower order bound}
O(sqrt(N) * log(sqrt(N)))
   {as noted before, log(sqrt(N)) == 1/2 * log(N)}
O(sqrt(N) * log(N))
                                  QED
```

Comment: I get this test failure on Codility's server: Compilation successful.

Example test:   [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2]
WRONG ANSWER (got 2 expected 3)

Detected some errors.example
example test✘WRONG ANSWER
got 2 expected 3
expand allCorrectness tests
▶extreme_min
extreme min test✔OK
▶extreme_without_peaks
test without peaks✔OK
▶prime_length
test with prime sequence length✘WRONG ANSWER
got 3 expected 1
▶anti_bin_search
anti bin_search test✘WRONG ANSWER
got 4 expected 7
▶simple1
simple test✘WRONG ANSWER
got 2 expected 4
▶simple2
second simple test✔OK

Comment: @user2286810 not really sure what you meant here or what exact tests those were...

the first example test you give is has 3 peaks in it:
1  2  3 (4) 3 (4) 1  2  3  4 (6) 2
and you can not place a flag on each of those peaks because the distance between in the first and the second peak is 2, therefore, the result is definitely 2, while your comment implies it's 3

also, your example does not match codility's example found at https://app.codility.com/programmers/task/flags/, which is:[1, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2]

so, you or codility just made a typo? or you're trolling?

Comment: @ Jurko Gospodnetić copy and paste the code below and run vs codility server....

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public int solution(int[] A) 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
        for (int i = 1; i < A.length - 1; i++) 
        {  
            if (A[i - 1] < A[i] && A[i + 1] < A[i]) 
            {  
                array.add(i);  
            }  
        }  
   if (array.size() == 1 || array.size() == 0) 
   {  
        return array.size();  
   }  
    int sf = 1;  
    int ef = array.size();  
    int result = 1;  
    while (sf <= ef) 
    {  
        int flag = (sf + ef) / 2;  
        boolean suc = false;  
        int used = 0;  
        int mark = array.get(0);  
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) 
        {  
            if (array.get(i) >= mark) 
            {  
                used++;  
                mark = array.get(i) + flag;  
                    if (used == flag) 
                    {                       
                        suc = true;  
                        break;  
                    }  
            }  
        }  
        if (suc) 
        {  
            result = flag;  
            sf = flag + 1;  
        } 
        else 
        {  
            ef = flag - 1;  
        }  
    }  
   return result;  
 }
```

Comment: An additional optimization you could make is returning array.size() for the case where array.size() == 2. If you think about it, any 2 arbitrary peaks in the array must have a minimum distance of 2. Thus if the number of peaks is 2, then 2 flags can be placed no matter what.

Comment: In the worst case this will be O(n log n) since the code basically does a binary search on the range of all possible values of K (the number of flags set). This range is 1..M where M is the number of peaks in the array. Since M is bounded by (N/2) - 1, M can be considered directly proportional to N, and thus the binary search outer loop is O(log N) and the inner loop in the second part is obviously O(N) since it iterates through all elements in the array. Thus in the worst case this is O(N log N) but Codility seems to accept this answer and gives it 100/100 even though they want a O(N) answer.

Comment: It fails on codility's server: Example test:   [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2]
WRONG ANSWER (got 2 expected 3)
Detected some errors.▶prime_length
test with prime sequence length✘WRONG ANSWER
got 3 expected 1
▶anti_bin_search
anti bin_search test✘WRONG ANSWER
got 4 expected 7
▶simple1
simple test✘WRONG ANSWER
got 2 expected 4
▶simple2
second simple test✔OK
expand allPerformance tests
▶medium_random
chaotic medium sequences, length = ~5,000✘WRONG ANSWER
got 70 expected 625
▶medium_anti_slow
medium test anti slow solutions✘WRONG ANSWER
got 68 expected 1

Answer (score 2):

C++ solution, O(N) detected

```
#include <algorithm>

int solution(vector<int> &a) {

    if(a.size() < 3) return 0;

    std::vector<int> peaks(a.size());

    int last_peak = -1;

    peaks.back() = last_peak;

    for(auto i = ++a.rbegin();i != --a.rend();i++)
    {

        int index = a.size() - (i - a.rbegin()) - 1;
        if(*i > *(i - 1) && *i > *(i + 1))
            last_peak = index;
        peaks[index] = last_peak;
    }

    peaks.front() = last_peak;

    int max_flags = 0;

    for(int i = 1;i*i <= a.size() + i;i++)
    {
        int next_peak = peaks[0];
        int flags = 0;
        for(int j = 0;j < i && next_peak != -1;j++, flags++)
        {               
            if(next_peak + i >= a.size())
                next_peak = -1;
            else
                next_peak = peaks[next_peak + i];            
        }
        max_flags = std::max(max_flags, flags);
    }

    return max_flags;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

100% Java solution with O(N) complexity.

https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingPNYEZY-G6Q/

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        int[] peaks = new int[A.length];
        int peakStart = 0;
        int peakEnd = 0;
        
        //Find the peaks.
        //We don't want to traverse the array where peaks hasn't started, yet, 
        //or where peaks doesn't occur any more.
        //Therefore, find start and end points of the peak as well.
        for(int i = 1; i < A.length-1; i++) {
            if(A[i-1] < A[i] && A[i+1] < A[i]) {
                peaks[i] = 1;
                peakEnd = i + 1;
            }
            if(peakStart == 0) {
                peakStart = i;
            }
        }
        
        int x = 1;
        //The maximum number of flags can be √N
        int limit = (int)Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(A.length));
        int prevPeak = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        
        while(x <= limit) {
            counter = 0;
            prevPeak = 0;
            for(int y = peakStart; y < peakEnd; y++) {
                //Find the peak points when we have x number of flags.
                if(peaks[y] == 1 && (prevPeak == 0 || x <= (y - prevPeak))) {
                    counter++;
                    prevPeak = y;
                }
                //If we don't have any more flags stop.
                if(counter == x ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            //if the number of flags set on the peaks starts to reduce stop searching.
            if(counter <= max) {
                return max;
            }
            //Keep the maximum number of flags we set on.
            max = counter;
            x++;
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

- There is a ratio between the number of flags we can take with us and
  the number of flags we can set. We can not set more than √N number of
  flags since N/√N = √N. If we set more than √N, we will end up with
  decreasing number of flags set on the peaks.
- When we increase the numbers of flags we take with us, the number of
  flags we can set increases up to a point. After that point the number
  of flags we can set will decrease. Therefore, when the number of
  flags we can set starts to decrease once, we don't have to check the
  rest of the possible solutions.
- We mark the peak points at the beginning of the code, and we also
  mark the first and the last peak points. This reduces the unnecessary
  checks where the peaks starts at the very last elements of a large
  array or the last peak occurs at the very first elements of a large
  array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C++ Solution with 100% score

```
int test(vector<int> &peaks,int i,int n)
{
int j,k,sum,fin,pos;

fin =  n/i;
for (k=0; k< i; k++) 
{
     sum=0;
     for (j=0; j< fin; j++) 
     {   pos = j + k * fin;
         sum=sum + peaks[ pos  ];        
     }
     if (0==sum) return 0;
}   
return 1;   
}

int solution(vector<int> &A) {
// write your code in C++98 
int i,n,max,r,j,salir;
n = A.size();  
vector<int> peaks(n,0);

if (0==n) return 0;
if (1==n) return 0;

for (i=1; i< (n-1) ; i++)
{     
    if (  (A[i-1] < A[i]) && (A[i+1] < A[i]) ) peaks[i]=1;   
}
i=1;
max=0;
salir =0;
while ( ( i*i < n) && (0==salir) )
{
    if ( 0== n % i)
    {
        r=test(peaks,i,n);
        if (( 1==r ) && (i>max)) max=i; 

        j = n/i;
        r=test(peaks,j,n);
        if (( 1==r ) && (j>max)) max=j; 
        if ( max > n/2) salir =1;
    }
    i++;
}

if (0==salir)
{
    if (i*i == n) 
    {

        if ( 1==test(peaks,i,n) ) max=i;

    } 
}



return max;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first idea is that we cannot set more than `sqrt(N)` flags. Lets imagine that we've taken `N` flags, in this case we should have at least `N * N` items to set all the flags, because `N` it's the minimal distance between the flags. So, if we have `N` items its impossible to set more than `sqrt(N)` flags.

```js
function solution(A) {
    const peaks = searchPeaks(A);
    const maxFlagCount = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(A.length)) + 1;

    let result = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= maxFlagCount; ++i) {
        const flagsSet = setFlags(peaks, i);
        result = Math.max(result, flagsSet);
    }

    return result;
}

function searchPeaks(A) {
    const peaks = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < A.length - 1; ++i) {
        if (A[i] > A[i - 1] && A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
            peaks.push(i);
        }
    }

    return peaks;
}

function setFlags(peaks, flagsTotal) {
    let flagsSet = 0;
    let lastFlagIndex = -flagsTotal;

    for (const peakIndex of peaks) {
        if (peakIndex >= lastFlagIndex + flagsTotal) {
            flagsSet += 1;
            lastFlagIndex = peakIndex;

            if (flagsSet === flagsTotal) {
                return flagsSet;
            }
        }
    }

    return flagsSet;
}
```

Such solution has `O(N)` complexity. We should iterate over `A` to find peaks and iterate from `1` to `sqrt(N)` flag counts trying to set all the flags. So we have `O(N + 1 + 2 + 3 ... sqrt(N))` = `O(N + sqrt(N*N))` = `O(N)` complexity.

Above solution is pretty fast and it gets `100%` result, but it can be even more optimized. The idea is to binary search the flag count. Lets take `F` flags and try to set them all. If excess flags are left, the answer is less tan `F`. But, if all the flags have been set and there is space for more flags, the answer is greater than `F`.

```
function solution(A) {
    const peaks = searchPeaks(A);
    const maxFlagCount = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(A.length)) + 1;
    return bSearchFlagCount(A, peaks, 1, maxFlagCount);
}

function searchPeaks(A) {
    const peaks = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < A.length - 1; ++i) {
        if (A[i] > A[i - 1] && A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
            peaks.push(i);
        }
    }

    return peaks;
}

function bSearchFlagCount(A, peaks, start, end) {
    const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    const flagsSet = setFlags(peaks, mid);

    if (flagsSet == mid) {
        return mid;
    } else if (flagsSet < mid) {
        return end > start ? bSearchFlagCount(A, peaks, start, mid) : mid - 1;
    } else {
        return bSearchFlagCount(A, peaks, mid + 1, end);
    }
}

function setFlags(peaks, flagsTotal) {
    let flagsSet = 0;
    let lastFlagIndex = -flagsTotal;

    for (const peakIndex of peaks) {
        if (peakIndex >= lastFlagIndex + flagsTotal) {
            flagsSet += 1;
            lastFlagIndex = peakIndex;

            // It only matters that we can set more flags then were taken.
            // It doesn't matter how many extra flags can be set.
            if (flagsSet > flagsTotal) {
                return flagsSet;
            }
        }
    }

    return flagsSet;
}
```

[Here is](https://codility.com/media/train/solution-flags.pdf) the official Codility solutions of the task.

Comment: This answer did not work for me.  It yields a score of 33%, earning a 0 in performance.

Comment: @horseshoe7 I just rechecked the solutions and both gave me 100% result. Are you sure that your challenge exactly matches [the one this post is about](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/10-prime_and_composite_numbers/flags/)?

Comment: Hmm, the task is the same.  I implemented yours in Swift, but don't see why that should matter since it's an algorithm.  I can look at my code again.

Answer (score 1):

My C++ solution with 100% result

```
bool check(const vector<int>& v, int flags, int mid) {
    if (not v.empty()) {
        flags--;
    }
    int start = 0;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if (v[i] - v[start] >= mid) {
            --flags;
            start = i;
        }
    }
    return flags <= 0;
}
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    vector<int> peaks;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < A.size() - 1; ++i) {
        if (A[i] > A[i - 1] and A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
            peaks.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    int low = 0;
    int high = peaks.size();
    int res = 0;
   
    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = high - (high - low) / 2;
        if (check(peaks, mid, mid)) {
            low = mid + 1;
            res = mid;
        } else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem:

1. you have to find peaks
2. calculate distance (indices differences) between every 2 peaks
3. Initially the number of flags is the same number of peaks
4. compare distance between every 2 peaks with the initially specified number of flags (`[P - Q] >= K`)
5. after the comparison you will find that you have to avoid some peaks
6. the final number of maximum flags is the same number of remain peaks

** I'm still searching for how to write the best optimized code for this problem

Comment: [5 - after the comparison you will find that you have to avoid some peaks] well what do you really means ? avoid peaks where |p-q}<=k ?

Comment: im doing the same thing in my code.. could you find something wrong in that ?

Comment: you have to compare against [P -Q] >= K NOT p-q}<=k

Answer (score 0):

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
     int p = 0;
     int q = 0;
     int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {

        if (i > 0 && i < A.length && (i + 1) < A.length - 1) {
            if (A[i] > A[i - 1] && A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
                p = i;

                if (i < A.length / 2)
                    k++;

            }

            if (i > 0 && i < A.length && (A.length - i + 1) < A.length) {
                if (A[A.length - i] > A[A.length - i - 1]
                        && A[A.length - i] > A[A.length - i + 1] ) {
                    q = A.length - i;

                    if (i < A.length / 2)
                        k++;
                    else {
                        if (Math.abs(p - q) < k && p != q)
                            k--;
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }
    return k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def get_max_num_peaks(arr):
    peaks = [i for i in range(1, len(arr)-1, 1) if arr[i]>arr[i-1] and arr[i]>arr[i+1]]
    max_len = [1 for i in peaks]
    smallest_diff = [0 for i in peaks]
    smallest_diff[0] = sys.maxint
    for i in range(1, len(peaks), 1):
        result = 1
        for j in range(0, i, 1):
            m = min(smallest_diff[j], peaks[i]-peaks[j])
            if smallest_diff[j]>0 and m>=max_len[j]+1:
                max_len[i] = max_len[j]+1
                smallest_diff[i] = m 
                result = max(result, max_len[i])
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = get_max_num_peaks([7, 10, 4, 5, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 3, 3, 7])
    print result
```

I used DP to solve this problem. Here is the python code:
The max num of flags can be set for array ending at i is the max num of flags can be set on j if min(min_diff(0 .. j), j to i) is no less than max_len(0 .. j)+1
Please correct me if I'm wrong or there is a O(N) solution

Comment: Never used python so absolutely no idea what are you doing in your code :-s. BTW did it worked for you ? could you write algo here ?

Comment: The algorithm works for me, it is in O(N^2) not O(N) and I'm trying to find a O(n) algo as well. The algo first get all peaks, in this case it's 1, 4, 6, 8. smallest_diff[j] means the smallest difference two peaks for sub array of peaks ending at j.

Comment: max_len[j] means the maximum number of flags for subarray 0..j and j is the last peak which has a flag. It starts from the second peak. For every peak i,  it search from the first peak to peak i-1 for a peak j such that min(smallest_diff[j], peaks[i]-peaks[j]) is no less than max_len[j]+1, if found then set max_len[i] = max_len[j]+1 and update smallest_diff. The result is the maximum of max_len array

Comment: Just fyi the solution in Java by francesco Malagrino which gets 100/100 score is O(n log n) since it's a binary search on the range of all positive numbers 1..(number_of_peaks) and the number of peaks is bounded by (N / 2) - 1. Still the O(n log n) is an extremely worst case type thing, and in the average case it is very likely overshadowed by the O(n) iteration. I don't really think it's possible to do this problem in O(n) but I'll ask around.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the answer had been provided by  francesco Malagrino, but i have written my own code. for the arrays {1,5,3,4,3,4,1,2,3,4,6,2} and { 7, 10, 4, 5, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 3, 3, 7 } my code is working just fine. and when I took my code on the codility exams i had failed on  {9, 9, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 8, 9, 3, 1}

my answer resulted to 3 maximum flags. the way I understand it it supposed to be 3 but instead 
the correct answer is 2, and also with also in respect to francesco Malagrino's solution.

what seems to be wrong in my code and how come the answer should only be 2 the fact that 
distances  between peaks 4, 6, 9 followed the rule.

```
private static int getpeak(int[] a) {
    List<Integer> peak = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int temp1 = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
    int temp3 = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= (a.length - 2); i++) {
        temp1 = a[i - 1];
        temp2 = a[i];
        temp3 = a[i + 1];
        if (temp2 > temp1 && temp2 > temp3) {
            peak.add(i);
        }
    }

    Integer[] peakArray = peak.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    int max = 1;
    int lastFlag = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= peakArray.length - 1; i++) {
        int gap = peakArray[i] - peakArray[lastFlag];
        gap = Math.abs(gap);
        if (gap >= i+1) {
            lastFlag = i;
            max = max + 1;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: not the correct solution
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingPJT5SN-BEP/

Answer (score 0):

I cam up with an algorithm for this problem that is both of O(N) and passed all of the codility tests. The main idea is that the number of flags can not be more than the square root of N. So to keep the total order linear, each iteration should be less than the square root of N too, which is the number of flags itself.

So first, I built an array nextPeak that for each index of A provides the closest flag after the index.
Then, in the second part, I iterate f over all possible number of flags from root of N back to 0 to find the maximum number of flags that can be applied on the array. In each iteration, I try to apply the flags and use the nextPeak array to find the next peak in constant time.

The code looks like this:

```
public int solution(int[] A){
    if( A==null || A.length<3){
        return 0;
    }

    int[] next = new int[A.length];
    int nextPeak=-1;
    for(int i =1; i<A.length; i++){
        if(nextPeak<i){
            for(nextPeak=i; nextPeak<A.length-1; nextPeak++){
                if(A[nextPeak-1]<A[nextPeak] && A[nextPeak]>A[nextPeak+1]){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        next[i] = nextPeak;
    }

    next[0] = next[1];

    int max = new Double(Math.sqrt(A.length)).intValue();

    boolean failed = true ;
    int f=max;
    while(f>0 && failed){
        int v=0;
        for(int p=0; p<A.length-1 && next[p]<A.length-1 && v<f; v++, p+=max){
            p = next[p];
        }

        if(v<f){
            f--;
        } else {
            failed = false;
        }

    }

    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 100% Java solution

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {

        int[] nextPeaks = nextPeaks(A);

        int flagNumebr = 1;
        int result = 0;

        while ((flagNumebr-1)*flagNumebr <= A.length) {

            int flagPos = 0;
            int flagsTaken = 0;

            while (flagPos < A.length && flagsTaken < flagNumebr) {
                flagPos = nextPeaks[flagPos];

                if (flagPos == -1) {
                    // we arrived at the end of the peaks;
                    break;
                }

                flagsTaken++;
                flagPos += flagNumebr;
            }
            result = Math.max(result, flagsTaken);
            flagNumebr++;

        }

        return  result;



    }

    private boolean[] createPeaks(int[] A) {
        boolean[] peaks = new boolean[A.length];
        for (int i = 1; i < A.length-1; i++) {
            if (A[i - 1] < A[i] && A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
                peaks[i] = true;
            }
        }

        return  peaks;
    }

    private int[] nextPeaks (int[] A) {
        boolean[] peaks = createPeaks(A);
        int[] nextPeaks = new int[A.length];
        // the last position is always -1
        nextPeaks[A.length-1] = -1;

        for (int i = A.length-2; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            nextPeaks[i] = peaks[i] ? i : nextPeaks[i+1];
        }

        return  nextPeaks;
    }
}
```

Comment: You consistently misspell Number as Numebr

Answer (score 0):

C# Solution with 100% points.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;



class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
    List<int> peaks = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i < A.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (A[i - 1] < A[i] && A[i + 1] < A[i])
            {
                peaks.Add(i);
            }
        }
        if (peaks.Count == 1 || peaks.Count == 0)
        {
            return peaks.Count;
        }
        int leastFlags = 1;
        int mostFlags = peaks.Count;
        int result = 1;
        while (leastFlags <= mostFlags)
        {
            int flags = (leastFlags + mostFlags) / 2;
            bool suc = false;
            int used = 0;
            int mark = peaks[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < peaks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (peaks[i] >= mark)
                {
                    used++;
                    mark = peaks[i] + flags;
                    if (used == flags)
                    {
                        suc = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (suc)
            {
                result = flags;
                leastFlags = flags + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                mostFlags = flags - 1;
            }
        }
        return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

100% working JS solution:

```
function solution(A) {
    let peaks = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < A.length - 1; i++) {
        if (A[i] > A[i - 1] && A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
            peaks.push(i);  
        }
    }

    let n = peaks.length;
    if (n <= 2) {
        return n;
    }

    let maxFlags = Math.min(n, Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(A.length)));
    let distance = maxFlags;
    let rightPeak = peaks[n - 1];

    for (let k = maxFlags - 2; k > 0; k--) {
        let flags = k;
        let leftPeak = peaks[0];

        for (let i = 1; i <= n - 2; i++) {
            if (peaks[i] - leftPeak >= distance && rightPeak - peaks[i] >= distance) {
                if (flags === 1) {
                    return k + 2;    
                }

                flags--;
                leftPeak = peaks[i];
            }

            if (rightPeak - peaks[i] <= flags * (distance + 1)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flags === 0) {
            return k + 2;
        }

        distance--;
    }

    return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

100 % python O(N) detected.

```
import math
def solution(A):
 N=len(A)
#Trivial cases
 if N<3:
    return 0
 Flags_Idx=[]

 for p in range(1,N-1):
     if A[p-1]<A[p] and A[p]>A[p+1] :
         Flags_Idx.append(p)

 if len(Flags_Idx)==0:
    return 0
 if len(Flags_Idx)<=2:
     return len(Flags_Idx)
 Start_End_Flags=Flags_Idx[len(Flags_Idx)-1]-Flags_Idx[0]  
#Maximum number of flags N is such that Start_End_Flags/(N-1)>=N
#After solving a second degree equation we obtain the maximal value of N
 num_max_flags=math.floor(1.0+math.sqrt(4*Start_End_Flags+1.0))/2.0

#Set the current number of flags to its total number      
 len_flags=len(Flags_Idx)
 min_peaks=len(Flags_Idx)
 p=0

#Compute the minimal number of flags by checking each indexes
#and comparing to the maximal theorique value num_max_flags
 while p<len_flags-1:
    add = 1
#Move to the next flag until the condition Flags_Idx[p+add]-Flags_Idx[p]>=min(num_max_flags,num_flags) 
    while Flags_Idx[p+add]-Flags_Idx[p]<min(num_max_flags,min_peaks):
         min_peaks-=1
         if p+add<len_flags-1:
          add+=1
         else:
             p=len_flags
             break
    p+=add

 if num_max_flags==min_peaks:
  return min_peaks
#Bisect the remaining flags : check the condition
#for flags in [min_peaks,num_max_flags]
 num_peaks=min_peaks
 for nf in range (min_peaks,int(num_max_flags)+1):
  cnt=1
  p=0
  while p<len_flags-1:
    add = 1
    while Flags_Idx[p+add]-Flags_Idx[p]<nf:
         if p+add<len_flags-1:
          add+=1
         else:
             cnt-=1
             p=len_flags
             break
    p+=add
    cnt+=1
  num_peaks=max(min(cnt,nf),num_peaks)  
 return num_peaks
```

I first computed the maximal possible number of flags verifying the condition
Interval/(N-1) >= N , where Interval is the index difference between first and last flag. Then browsing all the flags comparing with the minimum of this value and the current number of flags. Subtract if the condition is not verified.
Obtained the minimal number of flags and use it as a starting point to check the condition
on the remaining ones (in interval [min_flag,max_flag]).

Answer (score 0):

100% python solution which is far simpler than the one posted above by @Jurko Gospodnetić

https://github.com/niall-oc/things/blob/master/codility/flags.py

https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training2Y78NP-VHU/

You don't need to do a binary search on this problem.  MAX flags is the (square root of the (spread between first and last flag)) +1.  First peak at index 9 and last peak at index 58 means the spread is sqrt(49) which is (7)+1.  So try 8 flags then 7 then 6 and so on.  You should break after your solution peaks!  no need to flog a dead horse!

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(A):
    peak=[x for x in range(1,len(A))if A[x-1]<A[x]>A[x+1]]
    max_flag=len(peak)
    for x in range(1,max_flag+1):
        for y in range(x-1):
            if abs(peak[y]-peak[y+1])>=max_flag:
                max_flag=max_flag-1
    print(max_flag)**strong text**
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got 100% with this solution in Java. I did one thing for the first loop to find peaks, i.e. after finding the peak I am skipping the next element as it is less than the peak.
I know this solution can be further optimized by group members but this is the best I can do as of now, so please let me know how can I optimize this more.

Detected time complexity: O(N)
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingG35UCA-7B4/

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
        int N = A.length;
        if (N < 3)
            return 0;
        
        ArrayList<Integer> peaks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 
        for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) {
 
            if (A[i] > A[i - 1]) {
                if (A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
                    peaks.add(i);
                    i++;// skip for next as A[i + 1] <  A[i] so no need to check again
 
                }
            }
        }
 
        
        int size = peaks.size();
        if (size < 2)
            return size;
 
        int k = (int) Math.sqrt(peaks.get(size - 1) - peaks.get(0))+1; // added 1 to round off
        int flagsLeft = k - 1; // one flag is used for first element
        int maxFlag = 0;
        int prevEle = peaks.get(0);
 
        while (k > 0) { // will iterate in descending order
            flagsLeft = k - 1; // reset first peak flag 
            prevEle = peaks.get(0);  // reset the flag to first element
 
            for (int i = 1; i < size && flagsLeft > 0; i++) {
 
                if (peaks.get(i) - prevEle >= k) {
                    flagsLeft--;
                    prevEle = peaks.get(i);
                }
 
                if ((size - 1 - i) < flagsLeft) { // as no. of peaks < flagsLeft
                    break;
                    
                }
            }
 
            
            if (flagsLeft == 0 && maxFlag < k) {
                maxFlag = k;
                break; // will break at first highest flag as iterating in desc order
            }
 
            k--;
        }
 
        return maxFlag;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int solution(int A[], int N) {
    int i,j,k;
    int count=0;
    int countval=0;
    int count1=0;
    int flag;
    for(i=1;i<N-1;i++)
    {`enter code here`
        if((A[i-1]<A[i]) && (A[i]>A[i+1]))
        {



            printf("%d %d\n",A[i],i);
             A[count++]=i;
            i++;

        }
    }  

    j=A[0];
    k=0;
    if (count==1 || count==0)
    return count;
    if (count==2)
    {
        if((A[1]-A[0])>=count)
        return 2;
        else 
        return 1;
    }


    flag=0;
    // contval=count;
    count1=1;
    countval=count;
    while(1)
    {
    for(i=1;i<count;i++)
    {
           printf("%d %d\n",A[i],j);
           if((A[i]-j)>=countval)
            {
                printf("Added %d %d\n",A[i],j);
                count1++;
                j=A[i];

            }
           /* if(i==count-1 && count1<count)
            {
                j=A[0];
                i=0;
                count1=1;
            }*/

    }
printf("count %d count1 %d \n",countval,count1);
if (count1<countval)
            {
               count1=1;
               countval--;
               j=A[0];
              }
            else
            {
              break;            }


}
    return countval;
   }
```